# time based workflow during test class

Tags: unit-test, time-dependent-workflow

I couldn't find any documentation for this, so appreciate your assitenace.

Assume I have time based workflow which scheduled for future (7 days after the event), and then it update the record.
If it will be scheduled from test class, does the workflow update action will be process during the test and be part of the coverate (assume the WF field update causing a trigger to run)? 
Is this functionality was changed in any of the latest realese?

I can see it does running (according to debug log), but saw also old questions people asking how they can test time based workflow.

Comment: they never used to run during tests.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, only Scheduled, Batchable, Future, and Queueable actions can be unit tested. This is probably a lacuna, since unit testing really is meant for code, not configuration.

Comment: Thanks, seems you're right and it is not running.... I probably confused when debugging the process. Thanks

Comment: I second  @sfdcfox... unit tests arent meant for salesforce standard tools if I may call it that.